Is being placed on a "merit pool" a polite rejection?
I gave an interview two months ago for a role at an Australian Embassy somewhere in Asia. A week later, this embassy contacted my character references, but, a month later, it told me through email that it had placed me on a merit pool and would consider my application if a position similar to the one I had applied for would arise. Nowhere in its email did it explicitly say, though, that my application had been rejected or unsuccessful. I want to clarify this email with the embassy, but the email doesn't accept any reply. So, what should I make of the hiring decision? Is being placed on a merit pool a polite rejection? Thanks in advance for your answers and happy holidays!

Hi @lv4422. Could you add some detail on country, or if regional government, region, as I imagine this can vary.

Hi @Adam Burke! I just included the requested details in my post. Thanks!

Is being placed on a "merit pool" a polite rejection? - YES. You got the correct answer.

Quite likely it means

You didn't get the job you applied for. They either gave it to someone else or it evaporated.
You did well on the interview. You are perfectly qualified for the job and if another one pops up, you can take another short with perhaps accelerated interviewing.

Given that this is a government entity, I wouldn't put too much stake in the merit pool. Governments have tons of list that someone maintains but no one else ever looks at.


You did not get the position.  Keep looking for other positions.
They will “keep you on file” for future positions which may or may not have any effect. It should not affect your behavior in any way (deliberately apply to new jobs you see there, etc.)


While it is not a definite rejection, it is also not a definite acceptance. If you really need a job, keep searching.
You might want to ask them for some clarification, about what it means, but I would not get my hopes high.

Any end stage of an interviewing process that doesn't include you getting the job is a polite rejection.
Keep searching.
